# A subtle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

I have found this inequality in my papers and can't says where it comes from, this is it :

Let $a,b,c$ be the side of a triangle so we have :
$$\frac{\pi}{36}(\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+2\sqrt{a^4+b^4+c^4-a^2b^2-c^2b^2-c^2a^2}})(\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2-2\sqrt{a^4+b^4+c^4-a^2b^2-c^2b^2-c^2a^2}})\leq \sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)(-a+b+c)}{16}}$$

I have no idea to start this so any help is welcome .I will post my try tomorrow 
and if you can help me for the typo it would be cool .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of geometry and we can find an elegant solution :
Recall that the RHS is the area of a triangle ABC  and the LHS the area of the Steiner inellipse related to the triangle ABC we have directly :
$$S=\pi ab\leq S'$$

Wich is just your inequality where $a$,$b$ denotes the semi major and the semi minor of the [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse)

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is easy enough to show; recall that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Delta^2= (a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c) \\= -a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2c^2b^2+2c^2a^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now the RHS is $ \sqrt{A+\sqrt{B}} \sqrt{A-\sqrt{B}} =\sqrt{A^2-B}$ and simplifies (after a liitle algebra) to
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\pi}{36} \sqrt{3} \Delta.
\end{eqnarray*}
So the inequality boils down to
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}} \leq 1
\end{eqnarray*}
which is clearly true.